# Does not the intent work with image buttons?

Tags: android, android-intent, imagebutton

I try to using intent for change view 
in my code the same sentence working but in another activity it didn't working

```
nav_top_post = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_top_post);

        nav_top_post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeFragment.this, PostActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

in this part show me red line and show the message 
'can not resolve constructor intent'

I can't not find what this happening

- This is my frament_home.xml *

  ```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/bar"
      android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
      >

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="3dp">


          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/nav_top_post"
              android:layout_width="50dp"
              android:layout_height="45dp"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_top_post_add" />


          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="200dp"
              android:layout_height="45dp"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"
              android:src="@drawable/together_logo" />


          <ImageButton
              android:layout_width="50dp"
              android:layout_height="45dp"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_top_message"
              android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>


      </RelativeLayout>

      </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/bar"
      android:id="@+id/recycler_view">

  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
  ```
- This is my HomeFragment.class *

  package com.example.blogapp.Fragment;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ImageButton;

  import com.example.blogapp.Activities.HomeActivity;
  import com.example.blogapp.Activities.PostActivity;
  import com.example.blogapp.R;

  public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

  ```
  ImageButton nav_top_post;


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

      nav_top_post = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_top_post);

      nav_top_post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              startActivity(new Intent(HomeFragment.this, PostActivity.class));
          }
      });

      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      return view;

  }
  ```

  }

  - And i want to move PostActivity.java with use Intent method *

package com.example.blogapp.Activities;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.blogapp.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Uri imageUri;
String myUrl = "";
StorageTask uploadTask;
StorageReference storageReference;

ImageView close, image_added;
TextView post;
EditText description;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    close = findViewById(R.id.close);
    image_added = findViewById(R.id.image_added);
    post = findViewById(R.id.post);
    description = findViewById(R.id.description);

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("posts");

    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            uploadImage();
        }
    });

    CropImage.activity()
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .start(PostActivity.this);
}


private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
}

private void uploadImage(){
    if(imageUri!= null){
        final StorageReference filereference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "."+getFileExtension(imageUri));

        uploadTask = filereference.putFile(imageUri);
        uploadTask.continueWith(new Continuation() {
            @Override
            public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                if(!task.isComplete()){
                    throw task.getException();
                }

                return filereference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    myUrl = downloadUri.toString();


                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

                    String postid = reference.push().getKey();

                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("postid", postid);
                    hashMap.put("postimage", myUrl);
                    hashMap.put("description", description.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("publisher", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                    reference.child(postid).setValue(hashMap);

                    startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                    finish();;
                }else {
                    showMessage("업로드에 실패하였습니다!");
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                showMessage(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } else{
        showMessage("이미지를 골라주세요!");
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        imageUri = result.getUri();

        image_added.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }else{
        showMessage("에러가 발생했습니다.");
        startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}




private void showMessage(String text) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

```
    * This sentense working in another my class * 


     close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

what is the reason?

I hope to know what is the reason that show error message

Answer (score 0):

Change `HomeFragment.this` to `HomeFragment.this.getActivity()` in the `Intent` creation.

```
startActivity(new Intent(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(), PostActivity.class));
```

An Intent constructor needs a `Context`, usually an `Activity` (but could be an `ApplicationContext`, but that could be a completely different topic on its own). A `Fragment` is not an `Activity`, but has access to the parent `Activity` via the `getActivity()` method.

Notice that the `Fragment` must be attached to the `Activity` (usually this means "visible") in order for this method to work, but that's your case.

Comment: Thank you .. I was misunderstand that i was thinking that sentence working in fragment too

Comment: You're welcome. :) If this solved your issue, could you mark que question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an context as a first argument while using intent.

So, using intent in fragment, you have to use `getActivity()` instead of `HomeFragment.this`

After replacing that, It will be

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```